# mobilenet always predict same label

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained a mobilenet_v2 model to classify a 8 class image dataset. I used google's pretrain parameters for fine-tune and retrain net in my dataset, the accuracy improve fast during training,and reached 98% when training end.
but when I use this trained model to predict test image, it always output the same label.
I have tried vgg16 too. It works well

here is my code

## inference

```
def inference(inputs,is_training=True):
with tf.contrib.slim.arg_scope(mobilenet_v2.training_scope(is_training=is_training)):
    net, endpoints = mobilenet_v2.mobilenet(input_tensor = inputs,num_classes = n_class,conv_defs = V2_18_DEF)
print('mobilenet output',net.get_shape().as_list())
return net
```

## loss

```
def loss(logit,label):
    losses=[]
    with tf.name_scope('LOSS'):
        class_loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label,logits=logit)
        class_loss = tf.reduce_mean(class_loss,axis = 0)
        tf.summary.scalar('class_loss',class_loss) 
    regularization_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES))
    total_loss = class_loss + regularization_loss
```

## train_step

```
def train_op(loss):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)#
        return train_step
```

## test

```
def test():

    inputs = tf.placeholder(name='inputs',shape=[None,224,224,3],dtype=tf.float32)

    label_holder = tf.placeholder(name='label_holder',shape=[None,n_class],dtype=tf.float32)

    if(net_type=='mobile_v2'): 
        test_logits = inference(inputs,is_training=False)
    elif(net_type=='mobile_v1'):
        test_logits = inference_mobile_v1(inputs,is_training=False)
    elif net_type=='vgg16':
        test_logits = inference_vgg(inputs,is_training=False)
    predict = tf.nn.softmax(test_logits)
    predict_result = tf.argmax(predict,axis=1,output_type=tf.int32)
    true_result = tf.argmax(label_holder,axis=1,output_type=tf.int32)
    correct_predict = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predict,axis=1,output_type=tf.int32),tf.argmax(label_holder,axis=1,\
             output_type = tf.int32))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict,tf.float32))
    pos = 0
    acc = 0
    count = 0
    sess = tf.Session()

    ckpt_path=''
    try:
        ckpt_path = sys.argv[3]
    except:
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(output_path)
        if(ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):
            ckpt_path = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
    for var in variables_to_restore:
        print(var.name)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
    saver.restore(sess,ckpt_path)


    dataset = Dataset(classes,0.8)
    test_data,test_label = dataset.get_test_data()
    while(pos<len(test_data)):
        start = pos
        end = min(pos+batch_size,len(test_data))
        batch_img = test_data[start:end]
        batch_label = test_label[start:end]
        batch_data={}
        batch_data[inputs] = batch_img
        batch_data[label_holder] = batch_label
        batch_acc,p_result,t_result = sess.run([accuracy,predict_result,true_result],feed_dict=batch_data)
        print('batch_acc',batch_acc)
        print(p_result)
        print(t_result)
        acc += batch_acc
        pos = end
        count+=1
    acc = acc/count
    print('test acc',acc)
    sess.close()
```

## train function

```
def train():

    inputs = tf.placeholder(name='inputs',shape=[None,224,224,3],dtype=tf.float32)#
    labels_placeholder = {}
    label_holder = tf.placeholder(name='label_holder',shape=[None,n_class],dtype=tf.float32) #
    if(net_type=='mobile_v2'):
        train_logits = inference(inputs)
    elif(net_type=='mobile_v1'):
        train_logits = inference_mobile_v1(inputs,is_training=True)
    elif net_type=='vgg16':
        train_logits = inference_vgg(inputs,is_training=True)
    loss_op = loss(train_logits,label_holder)
    predict = tf.nn.softmax(train_logits)
    print('predict shape',predict.get_shape().as_list())
    predict_result = tf.argmax(predict,axis=1,output_type = tf.int32)
    correct_predict = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predict,axis=1,output_type=tf.int32),tf.argmax(label_holder,axis=1,\
             output_type = tf.int32))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict,tf.float32))

    for var in tf.trainable_variables():
        tf.summary.histogram(var.name,var)

    train_step = train_op(loss_op)

    #pretrain_restore
    all_variable = tf.trainable_variables()
    pretrain_vals=[]
    reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(pretrain_model_path)
    var_to_shape_map=reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
    for var in all_variable:
        print(var.name)
        if('Logits' in var.name):
            continue
        if(var.name.split(':')[0] in var_to_shape_map):
            print('restore',var.name)
            pretrain_vals.append(var)
    pretrain_saver = tf.train.Saver(pretrain_vals)

    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
    train_saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
    #tensorboard
    sess = tf.Session()
    merge_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./tensorboard/train',sess.graph)

    #init
    print('init & restore')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    pretrain_saver.restore(sess,pretrain_model_path)

    dataset = Dataset(classes,0.8)#
    data_amount = dataset.data_amount 
    each_epoch = int(data_amount/batch_size)
    total_step = int(each_epoch*EPOCH)
    global_step = 0
    test_data,test_label = dataset.next_batch(80)
    for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        pos = 0
        count = 0
        acc = 0
        while(pos<len(test_data)):
            start = pos
            end = min(pos+batch_size,len(test_data))
            batch_img = test_data[start:end]
            batch_label = test_label[start:end]
            batch_data={}
            batch_data[inputs] = batch_img
            batch_data[label_holder] = batch_label
            batch_acc,t_result ,loss_val= sess.run([accuracy,predict_result,loss_op],feed_dict=batch_data)
            print('batch_acc',batch_acc,loss_val)
            print(t_result)
            acc += batch_acc
            pos = end
            count+=1
        acc = acc/count
        print('=====test_acc===',acc)
        for epoch_step in range(each_epoch):

            batch_img,batch_label = dataset.next_batch(batch_size)#
            batch_data={}
            batch_data[inputs] = batch_img
            batch_data[label_holder] = batch_label
            merge_str,loss_val,acc,p_result= sess.run([merge_op,loss_op,accuracy,predict_result],feed_dict=batch_data)
            sess.run(train_step,feed_dict = batch_data)
            print('loss %f,acc %f, global step %d ,epoch %d,epoch_step %d' % (loss_val,acc,global_step,epoch,epoch_step) )
            print(p_result)
            summary_writer.add_summary(merge_str,global_step=global_step)
            summary_writer.flush()
            global_step+=1

        save_path = os.path.join(output_path,'model.ckpt')
        train_saver.save(sess,save_path,global_step)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the class balance of your training data? Could it be you are training primarily on one class, and thus are always predicting the same label? Seeing as how VGG16 works well, I do not think this would be the issue, but it might be worth looking at it.

Comment: I sample same amount of data from each class to make a train batch. so think it may not be the issue,but thanks for your comment.

Comment: I try to use the same one batch data in training and testing,the training accuracy is 100%,but when testing,it still predict all same class .I think the issue may in parameter restore. I print the variable to restore,don't find any problem,include the batch norm moving mean.